# Entity subscriber not called when entity is created within another entity subscriber

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.2

I have the following szenario:

- A user creates a `Scan`
- The `ScanSubscriber` listens to `prePersist`, `preUpdate` and `onFlush`
- In `onFlush` some rare cases may happen that require the `CampaignParticipation`, that is related to the given `Scan`, to complete. I update some other entities here and I also create a `AccountBalanceChange` for the related user. After that I just call `$unitOfWork->computeChangeSets();`.

This works pretty well until this point. Now the problem:

- I also have another `AccountBalanceChangeSubscriber` that listens to `postPersist`. So I expect that this subscriber is called when I persist the `AccountBalanceChange` I created in my `ScanSubscriber`, but this does not happen.

I also tried things like:

```
$cmf   = $entityManager->getMetadataFactory();
$meta  = $cmf->getMetadataFor(get_class($accountBalanceChange));
$unitOfWork->computeChangeSet($meta, $accountBalanceChange);
```

So my questions are:

- Is my expectation correct that this listener should be called or is there kinda limitation in "stacked listeners"?
- Or am I missing some "registration" to make the framework know about the new entity regardless that is persisted correct in my database?

The `AccountBalanceChangeSubscriber` itself works like a charm when I save a  `AccountBalanceChange` using sonata admin.

My code (very shortened):

`ScanSubscriber.php`:

```
class ScanSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'onFlush',
        );
    }

    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();
        $unitOfWork = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ($unitOfWork->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
            if ($entity instanceof Scan) {
                $accountBalanceChange = new AccountBalanceChange();

                $entityManager->persist($accountBalanceChange);
            }
        }

        $unitOfWork->computeChangeSets();
    }
}
```

`AccountBalanceChangeSubscriber.php`:

```
class AccountBalanceChangeSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'postPersist',
        );
    }

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        // This is never called in the case I described but works when I save the entity using sonata admin
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm just looking over https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/LoggableListener.php while analyzing your code.  Since the operation is pretty similar.  Have you tried explicitly calling `$unitOfWork->computeChangeSet($entityManager->getClassMetadata($accountBalanceChange), $accountBalanceChange)` after persist?

Comment: Not sure if that's the issue, but postPersist runs only after actual INSERTs happen ([here's](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2a239be45ec4e64c736e4277cde8bff376ef2402/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L1024-L1026) relevant code in `UnitOfWork::executeInserts`)

Comment: There are a gazillion limitations with doctrine listeners especially when trying to change entities.  Basically you are trying to do business logic stuff during a persistence layer operation.  Might want to see if you can implement the desired functionality outside of Doctrine completely.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I decided to refactor my code to move the logic from the "second" listener into a separated command. Just when I finished this, I figured out a very complex chain of "features" that caused me to think the subscriber is not called. Actually **it is called and everything is working as I expected in my question**, **but** there is another `UserSubscriber` that disallows almost all property changes for `User`s that are flagged as `anonymous` (in my case until they "claim" their account). And I forgot to whitelist the two properties I wanted to change in `AccountBalanceChange`.

So, thanks for the comments that directed me in the right way and have a nice weekend! :-)